# React.js combination of className and is attribute

Tags: reactjs

I have run into a weird issue in React. Normally when you set `className` it gets converted to class, but when you also set the `is` attribute, this does not happen. You have to use `class` instead. Is there a reason behind this behavior?

```
<div key={this.props.key} className='A B' is='x-custom-web-component'></div>
```

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you mean. What do you mean by the `is` attribute?

Comment: How are you creating your components? What version of React?

Comment: I'm using react 0.14.7. I'm experimenting with using custom elements from webcomponents in a react application.

Answer (score 1):

With web-components React passes all props directly as attributes. This is because a web-component could use an attribute called 'classname' and 'class' for different things. One exception is `style` which still uses an object.

Comment: So this is a special case behavior?